# Histogram of aggregate individual densities

Tags: r, aggregate, histogram, probability-density

I have database which is a set of experts' answers. They indicate for example, what will be the level of inflation next year by giving 5th, 50th and 95th percentile (`q1, me and q3` in code below). I want to plot a histogram of aggregated individual forecasts of experts.
(To be clear, q1 is a vector of 5th percentile of 6 experts)
Is it possible to prepare it in R? Any ideas how to make it? I'll be glad of any help :)

```
q1 <- c(-0.9, -0.8, -0.5, -0.8, -1.1, -1.0)
me <- c(-0.6, -0.5, -0.3, -0.6, -0.6, -0.4)
q3 <- c(-0.4, -0.4, 0.1, -0.4, -0.1, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

q1 <- c(-0.9, -0.8, -0.5, -0.8, -1.1, -1.0)
me <- c(-0.6, -0.5, -0.3, -0.6, -0.6, -0.4)
q3 <- c(-0.4, -0.4, 0.1, -0.4, -0.1, 0.0)
df <- data.frame(cbind(q1,me,q3))

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(q1,me,q3),
    names_to = "Quantile",
    values_to = "Values"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Expert = as.factor(id)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(Quantile = factor(Quantile, levels=c("q1", "me", "q3")))
  
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=Expert, y=Values, fill=Quantile)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
  geom_text(aes(label=Values), vjust=1.6, color="black",
            position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_pubr()
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly. It's like each of the experts creates his own density by indicate percentiles. It should be somehow aggregated into one density and then drawn as the histogram.

Comment: @TarJae Great option.  I like the chart

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if you want to calculate an average from the quantiles, you could `rbind` them and take the `colMeans`. Then you could overlay two `hist`ograms using `add=TRUE`, or better `plot` the `density`s which I show you here.

```
q <- colMeans(rbind(q1, q3))

plot(density(me), ylim=c(0, max(density(q)$y)), "My Plot")
lines(density(q), col=2, lty=2)
legend("topright", c("me", "them"), lty=1:2, col=1:2)
```

[image]